# Replacing Claris FD 2400 with R2000

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-front

My bike has a 2x8 speed Shimano Claris 2400 front derailleur and ST-2400 shifters. The FD is damaged. Can I replace it with the newer Claris R2000 FD? Shimano's [compatibility guide](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.8?types=road&cid=C-453&acid=C-455) indicates that it can be mated only to the ST-R2000 shifters. Is that really the case in practice? If it isn't, might I as well replace it with a Sora or Tiagra double FD (of the same stye/cable-pull)?
I understand how mix and match could be a problem with the rear derailleur because of different indexing but aren't all double FDs equal?

Comment: I'm trying to find a source to confirm it, but I'd be inclined to say that they're incompatible. It looks like the front derailleur design has changed to resemble the 9000/6800/5800/4700 series FDs, which are only compatible with 11 speed  or 4700 Tiagra shifters.

Comment: It's irritating that derailer manufacturers do not have a standard metric for "pull" so one can easily compare for shifter compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

The [road compatibility chart](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.8?cid=C-453&acid=C-454) does indeed say that the R2000 front derailleur not compatible with 2400 shifters.

Rear  derailleur actuation ratios are fairly well documented, but I've never found a good source for front derailleurs, I do know that you cannot assume that all double front derailleurs are compatible.

Your best best is just to replace with a 2400 series derailleur. Good news is that FD-2400 units are still available and and inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the newer claris design with the old shifters but it might not be satisfactory. To achieve the correct movement, the gear cable will be a little too loose in the lower gear or a little too tight in the higher gear (assuming the limit screws are set properly).

If it's all you have, yes you can achieve a functional setup but it's not the best option.